# Fusion Tables Layer infoWindow list

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to print queried FusionTablesLayer rows into a separate div rather than open the information in a standard infoWindow when a marker is clicked. Basically I am trying to show the info for each marker, just like you would get when doing a normal google maps search. The Google Maps API v3 seems to only pull information from FusionTablesLayers when you click on a particular marker. All of the JSON examples I have found to perform a similar task seem to use the SQL API for Fusion Tables, which has been deprecated. I need to find a way to query the table using an orderBy distance. The map query I am using is below and this query works perfectly for populating the points on the map.

```js
var Layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Latitude',
        from: 'table_id',
        orderBy: "ST_DISTANCE(Latitude, LATLNG"+latlng+")",
        limit: 50
    }
});
```

Comment: Just use the [new JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) instead of the old deprecated one. Here is a basic example  how to fetch data from FT with the new API: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/basic_jsonp_request

Comment: @Odi I am using the new API (v1.0). I have found the example you linked, but this uses the SQL API which has been deprecated. This example was last updated on April 25th, and the SQL API was deprecated on June 26th.

Comment: No, I think there is a misunderstanding. The example shows perfectly valid code for the new API. See the [migration guide to see the difference between the new and the old API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide).

Comment: @Odi You are correct, thank you for the clarification!! Sorry for the misunderstanding. Do you know if ordering by distance is possible? This example does everything else I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The [Fusion Tables API V1.0](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) is not deprecated.

You can also use queries from the [visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz_numbered_sidebar.html) with a simple sidebar

Comment: The Fusion Tables API v1.0 is not deprecated, it is the SQL API that has been deprecated and will no longer be usable as of December. I haven't found a way yet using the v1.0 API to do an orderBy distance query. Is there an example you could point me to?

Comment: Haven't started using that API yet, this is [the example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/basic_jsonp_request).  I have an example using [orderBy with the google visualization API](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz_numbered.html) (it isn't creating sidebar information, but it does show how to return the information).

Comment: When I view this in FF or Chromium, it doesn't seem to display anything on the side of the map but rather just popups when you click on markers. What should I be seeing? Thanks.

Comment: As I said in my comment, it doesn't have any information the sidebar (wouldn't be hard to add though), but it does an OrderBy Query of FusionTables and adds numbered markers based on the order.

Comment: Added an example with a sidebar

Comment: I would like to display more information for each item in the sidebar rather than having infoWindows. I believe I can use the gviz part of your example to accomplish this. Please correct me if I am wrong or doing it the hard way. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct.  Not knowing what you wanted to display or seeing your FusionTable (and given that the example table I was using didn't contain a lot of useful information) I didn't do that in the example.  Note that the google visualization query is limited to returning 500 rows, if you need more than that you will need to use the new Fusion Tables API v1.0, I don't have any examples that do that.